# Calling Function to display through id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvoucher(id){
    $.get("http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data,status){
        return data;
    });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("tr").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find("voucher_id").attr("href");
});
</script>
```

In the code i'm trying to make each row in the table clickable and that when clicked on the row, it would send it's voucher id to the data so then I could display the data in a dialog box. But i'm unsure of how to do it.

Comment: add HTML  code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in `document` ready function, also bind click to `td` in table

```
$(function(){
      $("table td").click(function() {
           window.location.href = $(this).closest("tr").find("voucher_id").attr("href");
      });
});
```